# PHP CURL Download File

Tags: php, file, curl, download

im trying to download a file from a url,
when I use the browser the download dialog works but when I use this code the new file on my server stay empty.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = "https://myapps.gia.edu/ReportCheckPortal/downloadReport.do?reportNo=$row['certNo']&weight=$row['carat']";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
$destination = "./files/certs/$row['certNo'].pdf";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

example of url: https://myapps.gia.edu/ReportCheckPortal/downloadReport.do?reportNo=1152872617&weight=1.35

Comment: You need to wrap array access in `{}` e.g. `"text{$array['key']}"`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solved this problem using this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
```

This is the final code:

```
$source = "https://myapps.gia.edu/ReportCheckPortal/downloadReport.do?reportNo=1152872617&weight=1.35";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "./files/test.pdf";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, ended up going with this solution which worked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107851/how-to-fix-curl-35-cannot-communicate-securely-with-peer-no-common-encryptio

Comment: I am getting empty data. But I am able to download the file directly from the browser

Comment: @user3345547 it was the issue with permission of the file. Once given the permission I was able to download it.

Answer (score 2):

Your url using https connection. Use the following curl option as well.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
```

Comment: added this line and got this error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to myapps.gia.edu:443

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you check if result actually contains data?
2. with `fputs` on larger files you need to specify byte length
3. Try using `file_put_contents($destination, $data);`

Comment: 1. did echo on $data and its empty, I don't know why. do you have any idea why when uses the browser I get a download dialog but with this it doesn't work?

Comment: Seeing you are requesting through SSL. If you don't need to specify the login for that URL then set the CURL option CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false. Also check what the error returned is with $error =  curl_error($ch); then print it out

Comment: got this error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to myapps.gia.edu:443

Comment: Set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Answer (score 0):

See if you can use the following code to help you.

//Create a cURL handle.
$ch = curl_init($fileUrl);

//Pass our file handle to cURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);