# cURL Error #:Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)

Tags: php, curl

When I run php-curl code , this error is coming

> cURL Error #:Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

and when i use `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3` in code then i get another error like

> cURL Error #:TCP connection reset by peer

Please help to solve this issue..

Comment: maybe duplicated here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107851/how-to-fix-curl-35-cannot-communicate-securely-with-peer-no-common-encryptio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107851/how-to-fix-curl-35-cannot-communicate-securely-with-peer-no-common-encryptio)

Comment: how to know which  SSL CIPHER method is used?